# why here 2 cannot implicitly convert to MyClass object?

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int){}

};
MyClass operator +(MyClass& lOperand, MyClass& rOperand) {
    return lOperand;
}

int main() {
    MyClass obj1(0);
    obj1 = obj1 + 2;  // 1
}
```

Here compiler says no match function of operator + in line 1. But I think 2 can be converted to a MyClass object as the constructor of MyClass is not explicit.
If I take & away from the parameter, then it is OK.

Comment: Try `const` for the parameters.

Comment: Use `const` so that `const MyClass& rOperand` can bind to 2 which is an rvalue. Non-const lvalue references (`MyClass& rOperand`) cannot bind to rvalues.

Comment: `MyClass operator +(MyClass&, MyClass&)` This signature tells me "two parameter by reference, *which will be modified*, and return a MyClass by value."  Why would you want to modify either parameter in a binary `+` operation?  That'd be very surprising behavior.  And upon further investigation, the routine does **not** actually modify those parameters.  In the code review, I'd ask:  Why are they mutable?  Why aren't they `const`?

Comment: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)

Comment: Strange `operator+` implementation... (but maybe that's beside the point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think 2 can be converted to a MyClass object as the constructor of MyClass is not explicit.

The **problem** is that after the conversion from `int` to `MyClass` we will have a ***prvalue*** of type `MyClass` which cannot be bound to an *lvalue reference to non-const `MyClass`*.

Basically, an lvalue reference to nonconst type cannot be bound to an rvalue. But an lvalue reference to a const type can be bound to an rvalue.  For example,

```
int &ref = 4; //not valid
const int &r = 4; //valid
```

---

To solve this, you can add a **low-level const** to the parameters as shown below:

```
//----------------------------------------- vvvvv----------------------->low level const added
MyClass operator +(const MyClass& lOperand, const MyClass& rOperand) {
    return lOperand;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/44KWve487)

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
MyClass operator +(MyClass& lOperand, MyClass& rOperand)
```

you are signaling that you are modifying the 2 arguments, because otherwise you surely would have used `const`, right?

But if the integer literal `2` is converted to `MyClass` you have a temporary object that will be destroyed at the end of the function call. Any modifications made to it will be lost.

Surely if you are going to modify arguments then you want those modifications to persist. So C++ in all its wisdom has decreed that a *prvalue*, which you get from the conversion from `int` to `MyClass`, can not be bound to an *lvalue reference to non-const `MyClass`. That way you don't loose your precious modifications.

But really `operator +` should not be modifying it's arguments, declare them as `const` and all will be well.